# Python: Where is the object getting instantiated and how can I pass arguments during object creation?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm building a RESTful API using Python Flask and flask-restplus.

It is a scaled flask-restplus application and I followed the page ([Scaling your project](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html)) given here to design my application.

I would like to pass arguments to the Ratings class during object instasiation. The Ratings class is decorated using the namespace decorators given by flask-restplus.

I'm not able to understand where the Ratings object is getting instatiated so that I can pass arguments to that object. The argument I must pass is a file name (settings.json) to Ratings class from my app.py file.

Any help will be much appreciated.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
|_>apis
|      |_> __init__.py
|      |_> ratings.py
|_>app.py
```

The three python files are like this:

```
#__init__.py

from flask_restplus import Api
from .ratings import api as ns1    

api = Api(version='1.0', title='Reviews Service',
          description='Hello Reviews',)

api.add_namespace(ns1)
```

---

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from apis import api

app = Flask(__name__)
api.init_app(app)
app.config.from_json('settings.json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename=app.config['LOGGING_FILE_LOCATION'], level=logging.INFO)

app.run()
```

---

```
# ratings.py

from db_interface import DBInterface
from flask_restplus import Resource, Namespace

api = Namespace('AppReviewRatings', description='"Ratings" related operations.',)


@api.route('/api/<version>/<metric_name>/<app_store_name>')
@api.doc(params={'version': '"1" (v1) or "2" (v2)',
                 'metric_name': '"rating" or "reviews"',
                 'app_store_name': '"apple" or "google"'})
class Ratings(Resource):
    @api.response(200, 'Success')
    @api.response(400, 'Validation Error')
    def get(self, version, metric_name, app_store_name):

        # I must receive settings.json as an argument from app.py file.
        db_interface = DBInterface(settings_file_path='settings.json')  
        parameters = {'app_store_name': app_store_name, 'hue_version': hue_version}

        result = db_interface.query(q_type=metric_name, params=parameters)
        return result
```

Comment: Could you please find any solution to that using the namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `__init__` function in your class like this:

```
# in your ratings.py
class Ratings(Resource):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.settings = self.kwargs.get('settings')
        # don't forget to call the super class
        super(Ratings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, version, metric_name, app_store_name):

    # get the settings here
    db_interface = DBInterface(settings_file_path=self.settings)

# app.py
# Initialize like this
api.add_resource(ratings.Ratings, '/api/my/end/point/',
             resource_class_kwargs={'settings': "path_to_settings.json"})
```

You can take a look at the source code <s>[here](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/fc99e651e62ddd1dfd7821817aea0bdebd6fed36/flask_restplus/resource.py#L29)</s> [here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/intermediate-usage.html#project-structure).

Comment: I tried your code to load Keras model inside __init__ function so that it should load only once, but it is loading, again and again, each time I am hitting get or post method. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested to initialize the **Resource** and use it in a **Namespace**.
This solution allows to pass argument to the resources from the main of the project. With the following project structure:

```
/project/src/python/
    app.py
    endpoints/
        __init__.py
       endpoint_a.py
```

Flask App and Api initialization.

```py
# file app.py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Flask

# load API modules as namespace
from endpoints.endpoint_a import api as namespace_endpoint_a

blueprint = Blueprint("My awsome webserver application", __name__, url_prefix="/")
# create main entry of the application (default namespace)
api = flask_restx.Api(
    blueprint,
    version="1.0",
)
# passing constructor parameters into resources
configuration_to_inject = {
    "my_custom_argument_1": "example",
    "my_custom_argument_2":"foo",
}
# first pass argument to RessourceA
for resource in namespace_endpoint_a.resources:
    # set config to ressource
    resource.kwargs['resource_class_kwargs'] = configuration_to_inject
    # then add Resource as Namespace to the API
    api.add_namespace(namespace_endpoint_a, path='/path/to/namespace_a')
    
# create a Flask WSGI application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["ERROR_INCLUDE_MESSAGE"] = True
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='8080', debug=False)
```

In the Ressource add a `__init__` function with parameter as defined in [flask_restx Ressource source](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_restx/resource.html#Resource)

```py
# file endpoints/RessourceA.py
from flask_restx import Resource
from flask_restx import Namespace

api = Namespace('namespace-name', description='Operations related to Ressource A')

@api.route("/")
class CalculationRequestsInbound(Resource):
   
    def __init__(self, api=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_custom_argument_1 = kwargs.get('my_custom_argument_1','foo')
        self.my_custom_argument_2 = kwargs.get('my_custom_argument_2','bar')
        #other staff...
        super(CalculationRequestsInbound, self).__init__(api, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self):
        return {"argument_1":self.my_custom_argument_1}, 200
```

`ResourceA.__init__(...)` function will be call once on the first HTTP call to the resource endpoint. Example

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/namespace_a' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Tested for Python 3.7.3 with packages `werkzeug==2.0.1`, `flask==2.0.2` and `flask_restx==0.5.1`
Solution based on [examples from flask_restx git repo](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/1352aabd90f4997af0931e3b1c11a78b5f11dad0/examples/resource_class_kwargs)

Extra to check what ressources are available for each registered namespace

```py
for _namespace in api.namespaces:
    print(f'Namespace:{_namespace.name}, {_namespace}')
    for resource in _namespace.resources:
        print(f'Ressource: {resource}')
```